Replica set member being added dies on detecting previous data when trying to sync from primary
After deleting any old replica's data by dropping local db on every host, initiated a new replica with a different replSetName.
Trying add another member and it finds history of previous replica when trying to sync from primary and dies:
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.984+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21358,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Replica set state transition","attr":{"newState":"STARTUP2","oldState":"STARTUP"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.985+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21306,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Starting replication storage threads"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.986+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21827,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-1","msg":"Updating term","attr":{"oldTerm":0,"newTerm":1}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.986+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21215,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-1","msg":"Member is in new state","attr":{"hostAndPort":"giftbutton.com:27017","newState":"PRIMARY"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.986+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":6788700, "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Received first command on ingress connection since session start or auth handshake","attr":{"elapsedMillis":98}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.987+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280513, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Initial sync required. Attempting to start initial sync...","attr":{"lastOpTime":{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}},"t":-1},"isInitialSyncFlagSet":false}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.988+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"REPL",     "id":9184100, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Previous data detected when attempting to start initial sync. Remove existing data in order to complete initial sync."}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.988+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":9184100,"file":"src/mongo/db/repl/replication_coordinator_impl.cpp","line":974}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-18T21:44:33.988+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

How do I completely delete history of previous replica sets this member has been of? Why is it finding the previous history of a replica set that different replSetName??
Any replica set stuff is kept in local db, which had been dropped when running without replication enabled. Where else the history is kept?
Any ideas are appreciated.

The error message is telling you what to do: "Remove existing data in order to complete initial sync."  It is detecting that there is already another replica set member in primary state, so in order to let it copy the data from the primary, delete, backup, and/or move the existing data directory and give it an empty one to start with.

Done all that. See the actual solution.
